# Visual studio xamarin can't run Android emulation

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Hi I have problem with xamarin on visual studio 19 and 22. I created a project xamarin.forms, installed sdk and android emulator Pixel 2 Pie 9 api 28, but when i start it i got an error:  **The system image of the device's "Pixel 2 Pie 9.0 - API 28" is incomplete and cannot be started.
Do you want to reinstall the image?**

I tried reinstalling didn't help, tried on PC and new laptop, didn't work but on other laptop it work and i don't know why. I tried on visual studio 19 everywhere.

**Edit:**

In device manager for android on Pixel 2 Pie9.0 api28 says that **the system image folder specified in config.ini does not exist**

config.ini last line: image.sysdir.1 = system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86\

copying files from working one didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I repaired it by moving the .android file and adding variables because I have a non-ASCII name in the default path of .android.
I had the error: `PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk]!`.